# Hardware requirements for Linux server to run R & RStudio

Tags: r

I want to build a home server/workstation to run my R projects. Based on what I have gathered, it should probably be Linux based. I want to buy the hardware now, but I am confused with the many available options for processors/ram/motherboards. I want to be able to use parallel processing, at least 64GB? of memory and enough storage space (~10TB?). Software wise, Ubuntu?, R, RStudio, PostgreSQL, some NOSQL database, probably Hadoop. I do a lot of text/geospatial/network analytics that are resource intensive. Budget ~$3000US.

**My Questions:**
What could an ideal configuration look like? (Hardware + Software)
What type of processor?

**Notes:**
No, I don't want to use a cloud solution.
I know it is a vague question, but any thoughts will help, please?
If it is off-topic or too vague, I will gladly delete.

Cheers B

Comment: I think this is a bit off-topic, as you're asking about hardware requirements for software. But it's also quite open ended since you're covering OS, to stats environments, to distributed cluster computing frameworks and databases. It's not clear what your use case requires from the sentence of description.

Comment: @SeanOwen, you will see that I already accepted Aleksandr Blek's answer before you put the question on hold. It was very well thought out and supplied me with heaps of material to work from - exactly what I was after. Please take the hold off unless you are on a power trip of course.

Comment: Just ran across [this comparative analysis article](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/thinkstation-p300-vs-hp-dell-workstation,1-1955.html) and thought that might want to read it, despite your focus/decision on Lenovo system.

Comment: @RUser I stand by my comment but happy for other mods to weigh in. Easy on the accusations, it's inappropriate. It is good you got a usable answer but it doesn't necessarily mean the question is on topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no ideal configuration, for `R` or in general - product selection is always a difficult task and many factors are at play. I think that the solution is rather simple - get the best computer that your budget allows.

Having said that, since you want to focus on `R` development and one of `R`'s pressing issues is its [critical dependence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5171593/2872891) on the amount of available *physical memory* (RAM), I would suggest favoring more RAM to other parameters. The second most important parameter, in my opinion, would be *number of cores* (or *processors* - see details below), due to your potential *multiprocessing* focus. Finally, the two next most important criteria I'd pay attention to would be *compatibility* with Linux and system/manufacturer's *quality*.

As far as the *storage* goes, I suggest considering *solid state drives (SSD)*, if you'd rather prefer to have a bit more more speed than more space (however, if your work will involve intensive disk operations, you might want to investigate the issue of SSD *reliability* or consult with people, knowledgeable in this matter). However, I think that for R-focused work, disk operations are much less critical than memory ones, as I've mentioned above.

When choosing a specific *Linux distribution*, I suggest using a well-supported one, such as Debian or, even better, Ubuntu (if you care more about support, choose their LTS version). I'd rather not buy parts and assemble custom box, but some people would definitely prefer that route - for that you really need to know hardware well, but potential compatibility could still be an issue. The next paragraph provides some examples for both *commercial-off-the-shelf (COTS)* and *custom* solutions.

Should you be interested in the *custom system* route, [this discussion](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/295552-28-multiprocessor-multicore-system-rendering-workstation) might be worth reading, as it contains some interesting pricing numbers (just to get an idea of potential savings) and also sheds some light on *multiprocessor vs. multi-core* alternatives (obviously, the *context* is different, but nevertheless could be useful). As I said, I would go the COTS route, mainly due to reliability and compatibility issues. In terms of single-processor multi-core systems, your budget is more than enough. However, when we go to multiprocessor workstations (I'm not even talking about servers), even two-processor configurations can go over your budget easily. Some, not far away, such as [HP Z820 Workstation](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/campaigns/workstations/z820.html). It starts from 2439 USD, but in minimal configuration. When you upgrade it to match your desired specs (if it's even possible), I'm sure that we'll be talking about 5K USD price range (extrapolating from the series' higher-level models). What I like about HP Z820, though, is the fact that this system is [Ubuntu certified](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201011-6754). Considering system compatibility and assuming your desire to run Ubuntu, the best way to approach your problem is to go through [Ubuntu-certified hardware lists](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification) and shortlist systems that you like. Just for the sake of completeness, take a look at this [interesting multiprocessor system](http://www.mediaworkstations.net/i-x2.html), which in compatible configuration might cost less than from HP or other major vendors. However, it's multimedia-oriented as well as it's reliability and compatibility are unknown, not to mention that it's way over your specified budget.

In terms of `R` and `R`-focused software, I highly recommend you to use *RStudio Server* instead of *RStudio*, as that will provide you with an opportunity to be able to work from any Internet-enabled location (provided you computer will be running, obviously). Another advice that I have is to keep an eye on *alternative `R` distributions*. I'm not talking about commercial expensive ones, but about emerging open source projects, such as `pqR`: http://www.pqr-project.org. Will update as needed. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I played a bit on the Dell's website and was able to configure two systems, which approach your main desired parameters (6-core, 64G of RAM, Ubuntu 12.04LTS) - albeit disks size is smaller (it's tricky) - and the total came to just a little above 3K USD. Models that allow you to do that are: Dell Precision Tower 5810 Workstation and Dell Precision Tower 7810 Workstation. Note that 7810 has additional benefit of optional second processor with a relatively cheap upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @Aleksandr Blekh, this provided me with so much more to take into consideration. I realized that I have to up my budget to ~$6K and I am going to go for a Lenovo P700 Thinkstation. Most of the Lenovo hardware is certified for Ubuntu. I am going for a single core that can support 64GB RAM (8x8), with ample cache 30MB and fast speed 3.4GHz. I also opted for an SSD drive for the OS and APPS, but mechanical HDD's for the data side.

Comment: @RUser: I am very glad that my answer was helpful. As for your choice, I can't say much, as I haven't had direct experience with the brand, just read some mixed reviews (in terms of quality control), but not too many to generalize. I hope that this option will work for you well. Would be interested in and appreciate your feedback after you set the system up and perform some R analyses.